# How to cancel task in Google Appengine? (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is my problem. 
If a user disconnect from channel and doesn't connect back in (let's say 5 sec) I can assume that he left my site.
If he does come back within 5 seconds I will cancel that task that was planing on doing something with that user.

How to achieve this? I was planning in using Task Queues but I don't know how to cancel it.

If you have any better idea, please share it :).

---

I have found my answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#Python_Deleting_tasks)#.

Comment: (Why the dissing of this question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the docs you point to explain how to delete tasks manually from the admin console, or how to call purge() to delete all tasks in a queue.

If you want to cancel a specific task programmatically, you'll have to implement a mechanism to do that in your code -- e.g. store a flag in the datastore that the task checks when it runs and makes it exit without doing anything when it sees the flag is set (or clear, or however you define the condition).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by

```
# Delete an individual task...
q = taskqueue.Queue('queue1')
q.delete_tasks(taskqueue.Task(name='foo'))
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#Python_Deleting_tasks